# (android)How can do the package name don't shown on phone application -> manage settings?

Tags: android, package

How can do the package name don't shown on phone application -> manage settings ?
I mean that I don't want it seen on application settings.My application's package name 
seen.
How I block this and rename it different?
(package name = com.ss.dd)

Comment: I found :) it is change on manifest file , application segment , set label (above icon)...

Comment: you should not do this manually. it later will result in annoying bugs (like Activitys aren't started because they are not found anymore or R.[id|drawable|string|xxx].XXX wouldn't be found anymore on classes using these ids. Refer to my answer and simply use AndroidTools. BTW why you won't have your application package inside settings?

Comment: I do not want to change my package name only ı want  in phone application settings package name seem s different name

Comment: problem is that the package name inside manifest IS ACTUALLY the name, android identifies your app. If you do it with suggested answer namespace of java files are kept, while imports and manifest entrys getting updated

Comment: for example my package name : com.xx.yy 
 ı change it 'book' not realy change only users when click application settings on their phone and see my application name book this is.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to release your own version of Android for this. Where you expose an API for developers to fake their package names!

Answer (score 0):

simply rename your application package before you build. You can archive this either through

Eclipse->right_click_On_Project->AndroidTools->RenameApplicationPackage

or

include a complete change of your namespace using an custom [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build script.
Also refer to [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html) on this topic

Answer (score 0):

I found :) it is change on manifest file , application segment , set label (above icon).